# batch file errorlevel set to 0 on startup

Tags: windows, batch-file, command, errorlevel

The errorlevel as soon as the .bat file is run is 0. However I am using errorlevel as a condition such as:

```
REG Query HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\test 2>NUL>>MMG.dat
If %ERRORLEVEL% == 0 goto turnon

REG Query HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\test2>NUL>>MMG.dat
If %ERRORLEVEL% == 0 goto turnon

REG Query HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\test 3>NUL>>MMG.dat
If %ERRORLEVEL% == 0 goto turnon
If %ERRORLEVEL% == 1 goto EOF
```

My problem is that if the errorlevel is already set to 0 then the condition becomes invalid.

Is their anyway I can work around this?

Note: errorlevel is NOT set anywhere within the file.

I am learning this language so please bear with me if its an obvious mistake

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean, "if the errorlevel is already set to 0"?  Do you mean that an environment variable with the name ERRORLEVEL is set?  (You can check by using the `set` command to list all environment variables.)  Otherwise, you don't have a problem, because any previous error level is forgotten as soon as you run a new command.

Comment: No enviroment errorlevels variables are set. When I start the script the errorlevel is already at 0 (I add echo ERRORLEVEL IS: %errorlevel% at the very top of the script to show the errorlevel) My issue is that I use errorlevel as a condition (see above example) and if the errorlevel is already at 0, then that condition becomes invalid from the scripts prospective. I have a number of reg query with the "if" condition under each one and if the reg value exists (errorlevel 0) alert the user with a goto command.

Comment: It doesn't matter what the error level "already is".  Each and every time you run the `reg` command, the error level changes, so when you test %ERRORLEVEL% you only get the result from the preceding command.

Comment: Following from this comment - some programs and commands do not set the errorlevel, so you have to check the program you are using.  `REG` does set the errorlevel so your code will work fine.

Comment: @foxidrive: true.  In that context it should be noted that whether a program sets the error level depends only on whether it is a GUI or command-line executable, so it isn't possible for a program to sometimes set the error level and sometimes not.  (Whether the error level returned is meaningful is an entirely different question!)  Internal commands could in principle set the error level only under some conditions, but as far as I know there are no such cases; each internal command either always or never sets the error level.

Answer (score 2):

I seem to recall that it's a bad idea to actually use the `%errorlevel%` variable itself for a variety of reasons, among them the fact it can be set manually which disconnects it from the actual return codes. For more detail, see [this item on Rob van der Woude's scripting pages](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/errorlevel.php), a valuable resource for all things scripting under Windows/DOS.

You should be using something like:

```
if errorlevel 1 ...
```

However, I'm not *entirely* certain what you're considering to be incorrect here. Yes, `%errorlevel%` *may* be set to zero before the script starts but that will be changed by the first call to `reg`, which will set it to 0 on success or 1 on failure.

If your intent is to do something should the `reg query` fail, simply use:

```
reg query 1 blah blah blah
if errorlevel 1 goto turnon

reg query 2 yak yak yak
if errorlevel 1 goto turnon

reg query 1 bjork brork bjork
if errorlevel 1 goto turnon
```

If it's to do something (like alert on any failing as per your question/comment) then what you have is okay, just with slightly different method and value:

```
set bad=0

reg query 1 blah blah blah
if errorlevel 1 goto alert

reg query 2 yak yak yak
if errorlevel 1 goto alert

reg query 1 bjork brork bjork
if errorlevel 1 goto alert

rem all queries returned success.
```

Comment: Sorry if I am wrong, but if a reg value is found the errorlevel should be 0 and thus goto turnon. However, if the errorlevel is already set at 0 and the reg value does not exist and the (if) condition is run, then it will still goto turnon as the errorlevel is 0

Comment: @DaE: no, if the reg executable doesn't find the key, it will set error level to 1. Try it with `reg query hkey_current_user` and `reg query hkey_nosuch_user` following each with `echo %errorlevel%`.

Comment: Thanks for your help on this. The if statement is actually to alert if the value is found e.g. `code REG Query HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\test 2>NUL>>MMG.dat
If %ERRORLEVEL% == 0 goto alert

REG Query HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\test2>NUL>>MMG.dat
If %ERRORLEVEL% == 0 goto alert

REG Query HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\test 3>NUL>>MMG.dat
If %ERRORLEVEL% == 0 goto alert
If %ERRORLEVEL% == 1 goto EOF` So the ideal outcome would be if the value was not found

Comment: @DoE, then you want the code as per my second sample, I'll adjust it as per your comment.

Comment: FWIW, I disagree that you should not use %ERRORLEVEL%.  Yes, it breaks if someone sets an environment variable of the same name, to which the obvious answer is "don't do that".  The `if errorlevel` command has a more serious problem in that it treats the error level as a signed value, so misbehaves for error levels above 2^31.  (These are more common than you might think.)

Comment: If I use the bottom script you gave the script will run the first command and if nothing is found it will goto no_alert without running the other queries? I need to run all queries, however if one value is found alert.

Comment: @DaE, then what you had in your question was the right idea, just with the wrong values. See my update to the second snippet.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Will look at restructuring my batch file.